# How to handle read-modify-write race condition in spring Webflux

Tags: java, spring-boot, concurrency, spring-webflux, race-condition

I have a race condition problem in Spring WebFlux (project reactor). I'm modeling a category-item relationship in which the category holds a reference to the number of items. Whenever an item is saved into the database the number of items in the category must be incremented. The below code is clearly susceptible to read-modify-write race conditions, but I'm not sure how to overcome the problem.

```java
itemMono.flatMap(itemRepository::save)
        .flatMap(item -> categoryRepository.findById(item.getCategoryId()))
        .map(category -> category.toBuilder().numberOfItems(category.getNumberOfItems() + 1).build())
        .flatMap(categoryRepository::save)
        .subscribe();
```

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Which database/driver do you use?

Comment: I'm using mongodb and spring data.

Comment: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/write-operations-atomicity/
Read more about atomic actions and read-modify-write problem.